# Instance variable resetting their value

Tags: java, libgdx

This code is showing strange behavior. The BaseActor class just call in order: initPhysics, initGraphics and onCreate (only once) and then act (for each frame). The expected behaviors is that in onCreate method I hold the `fixX` value (that actually is -6) to use the this value to set the X position of object each frame, for make the X axis of object static. I put a debug point in onCreate and act and he is called appropriately.
When

```
fixX = getBody().getPosition().x;
```

he get value 6, as expected, but in act the `fixX` value back to 0. 
When I change the `fixX` variable to static, the things works like expected. I don't realize how. I put a System out on the constructor of BirdActor to be sure the object is create only once. 
The methods setTransform of body is an Jni interface for C++ code of Libgdx with Box2d Engine.

```
public class BirdActor extends BaseActor {


   private float fixX = 0;

    public BirdActor() {
        System.out.println("Created");
    }

    @Override
    protected Body initPhysics() {
        return Assets.scene.getNamed(Body.class, "bird").get(0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate() {
        fixX = getBody().getPosition().x;
    }

    @Override
    public void act() {
        getBody().setTransform(fixX, getBody().getPosition().y, 0);
        super.act();


    }

    @Override
    protected Sprite initGraphics() {
        Sprite sprite = new Sprite(Assets.textureBird);
        return sprite;
    }

}
```

Comment: what's in BaseActor class ?

Comment: Is your code executed in multithreaded environment? If yes, then you should add a volatile declaration to the fixX variable.

Comment: My guess is that you're creating a new object instance every time, and so the second look at the value is seeing the value in a different object.

Comment: @Sanjeev: there is nothing important, only the call of the methods: initPhysics, initGraphics and onCreate in that order.

Comment: @Maxim: no, it's single thread, but I will try volatile when I go at home.

Comment: @Hot: I thought about that too, but the constructor is called only once, as I observe only one "Created" string on console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be because you call virtual method in constructor.

So the call list is:

```
1. BaseActor()
2. onCreate() of BirdActor
3. BirdActor() whitch inits the fixX = 0.
```

So initializing `fixX` is called after `onCreate()` method. Try remove the `fixX` initialization (`= 0`).